# how to use onclick with href on cgi perl

Tags: perl, cgi

I do have a list of files on page and next each file there is a link says delete, simply user by clicking the delete link it passes the file name on to the function  on the same script then it deletes the file from server and it says on the same page, any idea?

```
#some other stuff goes here such list of files 
print "<TD><a onclick='deleteFile()' href='#'>delete</a> </td>";

sub deleteFile()
{ 
    unlink ($file);
}
```

I also tried pure cgi perl and when I click delete link it prints error "Internal Error" but when I look for the file to see if it has been delete or not then the file actually deleted so there is no permission issue here else it wouldn't delete or unlink the file, here is what changed to:

```
print "<a href='../cgi-bin/deleteFile.cgi?param1=$dir&param2=$file'>delete</a>";
```

here what I have in deleteFile.cgi I get both param1 & 2 and use unlike like below

```
unlink($location);
```

Comment: You cannot call Perl subroutine from html tags just like that. Html should call a javascript function which should call a CGI file in backend which should invoke a Per subroutine. And, use Ajax if you want to stay on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You really haven't tried hard enough to find your own solution here.  I will give you some pointers ...

The onclick attribute in the HTML will trigger Javascript to be run in the browser (there are better ways to make a click event run Javascript code).

None of the Perl code in your CGI script will run unless the browser sends a request to the CGI script on the server.  Things that could generate a request include:

- the user clicking a link with an href that points to the CGI script (perhaps with the file pathname in a querystring parameter)
- the user clicking a submit button in a form with an action that points to the CGI script (perhaps with the file pathname in a hidden form field)
- some Javascript code in the browser that issues an AJAX request to the CGI script (with the file pathname as a POST parameter)

Clicking a link would result in a GET request - it is generally considered bad practice to run code that changes the state of the server (e.g.: deleting a file) is response to a GET request.

A form submission or an AJAX request can cause a POST request.  You could even explicitly use a DELETE request via AJAX.  These are more appropriate request methods to use for mutating server state.

Even when you get your code working, it will only be able to delete files in directories that the web server has write access to.  Web servers are not generally configured with write access to *any* directories by default.

Comment: Thanks Grant, I did try but I think not enough ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was after deleting there was no redirect so after adding redirect page then it worked like a charm..
    unlink glob ($file);
    print redirect(-url=>'http://main.cgi');

thanks